# Redis: How can I check how much memory used in real time?

Tags: memory-management, redis

I want check how much memory used in real time, for instance, each time I set or insert some data, I want to know how much memory increased and how much used totally.

I try to use `INFO` command, and check the `used_memory` or `used_memory_*` property would work or not, but sorry I found it only show the memory allotted by the system, cuz each time I check it after I insert new data, they still stay the same

Is there any way I can check the real time memory used in Redis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The used_memory field is what you are looking for. It is not the memory allocated by the *system* as you said, this is the memory given by the *process* memory allocator to Redis.

Example:

```
> info memory
...
used_memory:541368
...
> set y "titi"
OK
> info memory
...
used_memory:541448       # i.e. +80 bytes
...
> del y
(integer) 1
> info memory
...
used_memory:541368
...
```

Please note that Redis does a number of memory related optimizations. For instance, it is able to factorize values containing small integers. Or, if you append data to an existing string, the corresponding buffer will not grow at each append operation. So depending on these optimizations, the memory usage increase/decrease for a given set of operation is not always consistent.

Comment: how to test if redis has not yet hit the maxmemory limit used to query for health beside 'pong' ?